# WordPress, adding custom JS and Foundation js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am building my first WordPress theme and I am stuck on including JavaScripts on to the site.

I tried few different approaches adding it directly to the header hardcoaded and also in functions but it seams I can't get it to work.

Here is a line from functions.php

```
<?php
function _sf_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri().'
/js /foundation.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('foundation-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/foundation-orbit.js', array(), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'menu-effect', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js', 
array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_sf_scripts' );
?>
```

If someone can help me out here I would really appreciate it, thanks you!

Header PHP

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name');?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description');?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<?php wp_head();?>  
</head>
```

Comment: There may be an option in your theme to add extra JS files.. take a good look through the admin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually initialize foundation in a separate JS file, or with the following code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'so20558071_foundation_init', 9999 );
function so20558071_foundation_init()
{
    echo '<script>jQuery(document).foundation();</script>';
}
```

Comment: I will try this out right away I am still trying to figure it out.. Still not working.... Do I need to edit the actual JavaScript at all? Someone told me I have to edit all $ into jQuery inside the .js file

Comment: note that you have a space in your code: `/js /foundation.min.js`

Comment: Yes it if working finally.. TY.. diggy I would score you higher but I don't have adequate rep to do that.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
wp_enqueue_script('foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/foundation.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
```

With:

```
wp_register_script('foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/foundation.min.js", false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('foundation-js');
```

Do the same for the other scripts too.

And finally change

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_sf_scripts' );
```

To

```
add_action('init', '_sf_scripts');
```

Comment: make sure you have this <?php wp_head(); ?> in the <head> section (before </head>) of your header file.

Comment: Yep I do but nothing :( wired

Comment: could you paste the template file here?

Comment: I just added my Header section of header.php

Comment: hmm, make sure you include the header file into your template <?php get_header() ?>. Also, could you paste the html source code of the rendered page here as well?

Comment: I had a bracket in the wrong place in functions.php... I didn't even think to look at rendered page. but that gave me idea to look for functions.php error :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME:**

**FUNCTIONS PHP**

```
<?php
function _sf_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri().'
/js/foundation.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('foundation-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/foundation-
orbit.js', array(), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'menu-effect', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js', 
array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_sf_scripts' );

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'so20558071_foundation_init', 9999 );
function so20558071_foundation_init()
{
   echo '<script>jQuery(document).foundation();</script>';
}

?>
```

**FOOTER PHP**

```
<!-- Java Scripts -->
<script>
document.write('<script src= <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>' +
('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
 '.js><\/script>')
 </script>
```